# Run sql query unless condition fulfil in Python MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, while-loop

I have a cron job, which returns unique id, that I will use in sql query, which return me number of records with that id,

let's say, id = 78, Table is 'Student',

Now I am running query:
`query = select count(*) from students where id = 78`,

it will return me 1, then I will delete that record, now next time, it will be different id..
I want to run the cycle again and again, until it returns me 0 count.

Now I am running following logic, but it is not working:

```
def check_delete_link_between_student_account(self, student_id: int):
    count_query = None
    while count_query == 0:
        query = (f"DELETE FROM student "
                 f"WHERE student_id={student_id};")
        self.db_client.run_query(query)
        count_query = (f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {self.student} "
                       f"WHERE student_id={student_id};")
        self.db_client.run_query(count_query)
```

But its not running, where I am having a problem.

Comment: The condition `count_query == 0` isn't true when you start the loop, since you did `count_query = None` on the line before.

Comment: Can you share proper answer to that?

Comment: I don't understand why you have the loop in this function. `student_id` doesn't change during the loop.

Comment: I guess you want `while count_query != 0:`. But you need to set `count_query` to the value returned by the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query, not the string.

Comment: Your question says "next time it will be a different id". How does the id change in the loop? I think what you want is to return the count from the function, and call the function in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the loop in the function, since `student_id` doesn't change. You should call the function in a loop with different student IDs. And the function should return the count.

You need to get the count *before* it deletes the rows, otherwise the count will always be `0`.

```
def check_delete_link_between_student_account(self, student_id: int):
    self.db_client.cursor.execute(f"""
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {self.student}
        WHERE student_id = ?""", (student_id,))
    student_count = self.db_client.cursor.fetchone()[0]
    self.db_client.cursor.execute(f"
        DELETE FROM {self.student}
        WHERE student_id = ?""", (student_id,))
    return student_count
```

I've changed the queries to use prepared statements with placeholders. I had to make up `self.db_client.cursor` to get the cursor from your database connection -- you don't seem to be using a well-known ORM so I don't know the actual code should be. And `?` might need to be changed to `%s` depending on the database you're using.

Comment: student_id is the id, which get from cron job, thats what I mentioned on question.

Comment: But you said it should change each time through the loop, and the loop should repeat until the count is 0. It doesn't change in your question.